# Get distinct column values with a Spring Data JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this entity (annotations omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    private String category;

    @Lob
    private String name;

    @Lob
    private String customer_number;

    // more attributes omitted
}
```

I have to get a list of distinct `category` value for a particular `uid`

In my `JpaRepository` I have this:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT product.category FROM Product as product WHERE product.customerNumber = :cn ORDER BY product.category")
Page<String> findDistinctCategoryByCustomerNumber(String cn,
                                                  Pageable pageable);
```

Without the `@Query` annotation, the ids are returned, instead of the `category` values.  The generated SQL looks like this:

```
select distinct product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.customer_number as customer2_0_, product0_.category as directory3_0_, product0_.name as name4_0_ from product product0_ 
where product0_.customer_number=? 
order by product0_.id desc limit ?
```

But I need the distinct categories not the product entities.  Short of another idea I added the `@Query` annotation above.  But now I get this error:

```
Order by expression "PRODUCT0_.ID" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement:
select distinct product0_.directory as col_0_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.customer_number=? order by product0_.directory, product0_.id desc limit ? [90068-197]
```

But I cannot add `id` to the result list because that would make the `DISTINCT` useless, as `id` is the primary key.

So I either need a suitable method name for automatic query generation or a way to stop JpaRepository from adding its `order by` clause to the end of my `@Query`.

Comment: `order by` is used for sorting the result set. If `id` is in the `order by` criteria but not the result set, then it won't work

Comment: @Dovmo I *don't* want to order by id. This is added by JpaRepository. The question is about how to avoid that.

Comment: The error you're getting above says your query contains the `order by` clause: `...order by product0_.directory, product0_.id desc limit ? [90068-197]`

Comment: @Dovmo I know how ordering in sql works. But the `order by id` is added automatically, not by my code. I want to get rid of it. That is the question.

Comment: Oh I see. So you're using exactly that JPQL query (in the `@Query` annotation) and it's generating that invalid SQL?

Comment: @Dovmo Yes, exactly. I either have to find a way to suppress the `order by id` for the explicit SQL, or to find a method name that does the job automatically.

Comment: Spring Data repositories do not modify queries on their own. See [this sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/54187314) based on the question to verify this. Please show the real code where the problem exists. The current code has errors - the entity field is named `customer_name`, but is referred to as `customerName` in `@Query`. This would result in a different type of error. Also add the real code which calls `findDistinctCategoryByCustomerNumber`, showing how the `Pageable` parameter is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted `order by` gets created since you are requesting a paged result. The notion of the n-th page only makes sense when your results are ordered and the ordering is coming from your `Pageable` method argument.

Remove the `order by` from your query and set the `sort` attribute of your `Pageable` to sort by category.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I set the sort attribute?

Comment: `PageRequest.of(page, size, ASC, "category")` should do the trick https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction-java.lang.String...-